# What part # is this? (Is it even LEGO?)

Tags: part-identification

I have a bunch of these little curved yellow pins with a ball at the end. Are they LEGO? If so, what part are they?

(2x2 Orange brick for size comparison)

[image]

Comment: I would guess it's not LEGO, the color would be very unusual if it was.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like the arm of a Minion minifigure by Mega Bloks / Mega Construx without the hand.

[image: MegaBloks Minion]